# To block the main thread while a timer is running C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, synchronization

I am trying to do something with a timer in a loop and after the timer finishes its work, app starts another turn in the loop. But because I don't know how to ask the main thread stop running while timer is running, the main thread goes to the next turn immediately.

I did something about lock.

This is the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < step; i++)
{
    Monitor.Enter(locker);
    //start timer
}
```

then the code inside of the timer

```
t_tick = (senders, args) =>
{

   if (condition)
   {   
      //do something
   }
   else
   {
      //do something
      Monitor.Exit(AirplaneManager.locker);
      t.Stop();
   }
};
t.Tick += t_tick;
t.Interval = 30;
t.Start();
```

But this gives me an exception while the code runs into the monitor in timer : Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Is there any solution? Or I can use other way to reach my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of app is this?  A command line app?  WinForms?  WPF?  Other?  If you want your main thread to block, then why do you need the other thread anyway?

Comment: Sorry I only use Java but this looks really similar to a problem I had there--In java I'd put a synchronized() block around Monitor.enter()... Does C# have a similar construct?

Comment: WindForms. For instance, code line A, Timer.Start(), code line B. I hope the app can only start running on line B when it finishes timer's running.

Comment: Bill K, ja, I tried to use synchronization as well, but seems c# don't use the same way to call synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current thread to block for a set timespan, you can just use Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx

You don't need to use another thread.

Comment: It is not complete a Thread thing. I think a timer can be regard as a thread sometimes, but in my imagination, it is part of the main thread, so my original design is when it runs, the main should wait until it stops.

Comment: I have always looked at c# timers as mechanisms to perform repeated (or interval-based) actions asynchronously. But if you want to block the main thread until the timer is done - you can:
have the main thread wait one:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx

and have the timer flag the waithandle when its done (there is an example on the msdn page)

Comment: how do you lock a timer？just use lock keyword to lock  an object and make the bracket surrounding the timer？